# How to let client detect updated data from server?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, client-server, python-asyncio

I am currently making a simple client-server chatroom, but I am struggling with what the server should do when a new message appears.

My current solution is to just send the updated data to the client when they update theirs. In practice, this would mean that a client would only get new messages when they send a message themselves. Not very useful...

I also thought of another way, which is to have the client request the server for information every 3 or so seconds, but that would clog up the server with a large number of people.

My third idea would be to have the server connect to the clients when a new message appears, but that would need the server to remember their IP address and have the client use a server too. (Sounds like P2P.)

Most of my code is copied from [this part of the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/asyncio-stream.html#examples) so you can check against it too.

---

Here is my current client side code.
(Note: To send a 'message', you need to type `asyncio.run(echo_client('username', 'message'))`. This is Python 3.7+ only too.)

```
import asyncio

async def echo_client(user, message):
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(
        '127.0.0.1', 41001)

    user = str(user)
    message = ''.join(message.split('\n'))
    print(f'Sending from {user}: {message}')
    writer.write((user + '\n').encode())
    writer.write((message + '\n').encode())
    await writer.drain()

    data = await reader.readline()
    data = data.decode().strip()
    if data == 'Connection closed':
        print('User disconnected')
    else:
        print('Users info')
        for i in range(int(data)):
            user = await reader.readline()
            data = await reader.readline()
            user = user.decode().strip()
            data = data.decode().strip()
            print(f'{user}: {data}')
        # end for

    print('Connection closed')
    writer.close()
```

---

Here is my server side code. This just relays info stored on its side and updates them when needed.

```
import asyncio

users = {}

async def handle_echo(reader, writer):
    global users

    user = await reader.readline()
    data = await reader.readline()
    addr = writer.get_extra_info('peername')

    user = user.decode().strip()
    data = data.decode().strip()

    if data == '':
        print(f'Recieved empty message from {addr!r}')
        print(f'Closing connection to {addr!r}')
        writer.write(b'Connection closed')
        writer.close()
        del users[user]
        return

    if data != 'update':
        users[user] = data

    print(f'Received {data} from {addr!r}')

    print(f'Send: {[(i, j) for i, j in users.items()]}')
    writer.write(f'{len(users)}\n'.encode())
    await writer.drain()
    for user, data in users.items():
        writer.write(f'{user}\n{data}\n'.encode())
        await writer.drain()
    # end for

    print('Closed the connection')
    writer.close()

async def main():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(
        handle_echo, '127.0.0.1', 41001
    )

    addr = server.sockets[0].getsockname()
    print(f'Serving on {addr}')

    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()

asyncio.run(main())
```

---

My code works all fine, but I'm wondering for a better alternative. Please explain how your implementation works and how it would improve the code.

(I'll be going to bed in a while, so I'll see you tomorrow.)
(Not immediately of course ^v^)

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/websockets/

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0206/#batteries-included-philosophy

Comment: It is almost always faster to learn something than to create it.  And if you learn something you will already know it the next time you need it.

Comment: That's actually pretty true. Unfortunately I'd like to stay in safe territory for now. Refusal of the Call (monomyth amirite ha...).

Answer (score 0):

I would use a sockets library like https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ based on socket.io

The examples there will get you started.